# Is the detached HEAD my current project files or not?

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I'm following instructions for a kernel project and am told to:

> Export the kernel to use from the repository at the URL:
>
> git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.14
>
> You will need to switch to the 'v3.14.26' tag,

So I did:

`git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/linux-yocto-3.14`

Once the project downloaded, I typed in:

`git checkout 'v3.14.26'`

and was greeted with a message about how I'm now in **detached HEAD** state. It also output the following:

`HEAD is now at 356a3e1... Linux 3.14.26`

But it seemed weird that nothing in the project downloaded or changed; I ran `show-branch` and was told `[master] Merge tag 'v3.14.24'`

So is the project actually at version 3.14.26 or not? I don't really get what's going on, though I think I understand what's happening with **detached HEAD** after reading about it. I'm not going to be making any changes to the solution, I'm just following the guide to use the specific 3.14.26 version of the kernel.

Comment: Read this excellent answer regrading detached HEAD
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping things simple, HEAD will only be attached if it's pointing to a Branch (something you can commit to). When you point your HEAD to a Tag, your working copy will be based on that commit, but since you cannot commit to a Tag, it will tell you are detached.

To make sure you are where you think you are, run:

```
git log --decorate=short --oneline --branches=*
```

If it places HEAD on the same commit as v3.14.26, you're good. Example:

```
λ git log --decorate=short --oneline --branches=*

bdeddd5 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) XXX
5250588 YYY
647f007 ZZZ
d5cc025 (HEAD, tag: v3.14.26) WWW
55736b0 PPP
```

Comment: Thanks. So did I get the v3.14.26 version that I wanted? Or did I type in the wrong commands?

Comment: You did right :) Your code is in fact on v3.14.26. Edit with some more info

Comment: I executed the line you wrote and at the top of the list is `(origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge tag 'v.3.14.24'` :/ And then below that is a ton of commits that only go back in version (.23, .22, etc.)

Comment: If I re-execute `git chechout 'v3.14.26' it again tells me 'HEAD is now at 356a3el... Linux 3.14.26` yet when I use the line you told me, I see (among all the other commits) `Merge tag 'v3.14.24'. I don't see anything about the head being at v3.14.26

Comment: It probably is, but it's way behind the latest commits... try to grep on lines containing HEAD or this tag to make sure

Comment: I grepped and found nothing at all saying I'm on v3.14.26 :/

Comment: Am I checkout wrong? Maybe I don't want to checkout? lol all I am trying to do is update from v3.14.24 to v3.14.26

Comment: You just need the code, right? You won't make any change to the repository nor care about git history.

Comment: Yeah, just the code. I ended up typing `git show` and that showed me that I'm on 3.14.26 :P

Comment: Great! If you think the answer helped you in any way, do not forget to accept it.